# Network Error in react after deploy on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I deployed my MERN project on heroku app but when I tried to submit my form it send me this error in console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/api/products' from origin
> 'https://thebeuter.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
> data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. Form.jsx:69 Error: Network
> Error
> at e.exports (createError.js:16)
> at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (xhr.js:83)

Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    cors = require("cors"),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8000,
    db = "beuter",
    path = require("path"),
    server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening to on port ${port}`));

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static('beuter/build'))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'beuter', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}

console.log(port)

require("./server/config/database.config")(db);
require("./server/routes/product.route")(app);
```

and here is my Form.jsx:

```
const addProduct = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const product = {
      title,
      title_url,
      price,
      description1,
      description2,
      description3,
      description4,
      description5,
      img_url1,
      img_url2,
      img_url3,
      img_url4,
      size,
      size2,
      fit,
      fit2,
      category,
    };
    axios
      .post("localhost:8000/api/products", product)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.errors) {
          setErrors(res.data.errors);
        } else {
          navigate("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
...
...
...
)
```

How can I fix this?
Here is my project github:
https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Thank you!

Updated:

`ShopAllProducts.jsx`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/products");
      setProducts(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    document.title = `Shop - The Beuter`;
    fetchItems();
  }, [props]);
```

Comment: Your endpoint needs to be hitting your deployed server, not localhost. Read up about `CORS`

Comment: How can I fix my post.(localhost:8000...)

Comment: Try removing `localhost:8000` from the post request

Comment: `.post` worked fine after took out the localhost:8000 but `.get` it give me this error `TypeError: e.map is not a function`

Comment: Which `.get()` call is throwing the error?

Comment: Just updated in my question

Comment: Are you certain `res.data` returns an array? The error seems to suggest that `res.data` is an object

Comment: Yea... with localhost:8000 it worked fine but when I tried to take it out it gave me that error

Comment: In that case, try using `http://localhost:8000/api/products` for both `.post()` and `.get()` requests

Comment: @nathannewyen Did you resolve this issue? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

the answer for this question is to have `env` files for `development` and `production`

for `development`
create the file called `.env.development` in the root folder of your frontend app

[image]

in `.env.development` add this line

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL="http:localhost:5000"
```

and in `.env.production` add another line as

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL="https://algorithammer.herokuapp.com"
```

or your website (here i am showing the sample)

now make sure that you have a variable called `baseURL` as global variable

example:
`authAPI.js` (example)

```js
exports.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;
```

in `Login.js` (example)

```js
import {baseURL} from "./authAPI.js"

 axios
      .post(`${baseURL}/login`, {
        data: "sample data"
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

dont forget to push the changes and deploy the heroku app again